# How to deploy tornado page on nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, tornado

I am learning the tornado and try to deploy the page on nginx.

I open the nginx.conf and then add the the following..

```
server{
                listen 80;
                server_name _;
                location / {
                        root /home/ubuntu/tornado;
                        index index.html;
                }
        }
```

then I could see the page ....

However, the tornado/python code on the html is not be executed... it just displays on the page like the following ..

```
{% from util import Utility %} {% for info in infos %} 
{% end %}
{{ Utility.DecodeCharacter(info[1]) }}
{{ Utility.DecodeCharacter(info[2]) }}
```

Is there anything that I have not done,yet ? thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure your Nginx server to act as a [proxy](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) .
Here is a minimal example wich will serve static files from Nginx and will act as a proxy for your tornado application .

```
http {
    # Enumerate all the Tornado servers here
    upstream frontends {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    # ...

    server {
        listen 80;
        # ...

        location ^~ /static/ {
            # Path of your static files
            root /var/www;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://frontends;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that your Tornado application should be running on port 8000  (In addition to nginx service ).